# Using Grunt in a custom deployment script

Tags: azure, gruntjs

I am using Grunt in a custom deployment script for my Azure website. The Gruntfile is kind of big and it takes maybe two minutes to run. Everything was fine until a few days, the build just stops while running Grunt with a message: `The application was terminated.`

The weirdest thing about that, is that sometimes it works! So this is not an issue related to my Gruntfile.

This is how I call Grunt:

```
call node %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt --no-color
```

Is it possible that it is a timeout issue or something like that?

Comment: How long can this command run? Is ```The application was terminated.``` the only error message you get?

Comment: Yep, can't get more infos, I tried to add --stack option when calling Grunt. The build is actually not taking more than 5 minutes.

Comment: My build script included grunt-contrib-requirejs, looks like disabling the log of this task may have solved my issue.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problems when deploying Ghost to an Azure Web Site (shared).  See https://github.com/JayBeavers/Ghost for a repo.  Termination occurs at ~160 seconds.